# How to order by most results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a list of posts with associated author_ids, and I'm selecting a list of posts where each author has at least one published post like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT author_id 
FROM posts 
WHERE status = "live" AND author_id NOT IN(0,1)
```

I would like to sort that list top to bottom by the amount of posts created, but I don't know how to count them up and sort the list by that count.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to get the posts count

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) as posts_count
FROM posts 
WHERE status = "live" AND author_id NOT IN(0,1)
GROUP BY author_id
ORDER BY posts_count DESC;
```

Comment: I didn't know I could add the count(*) as a variable. Good to know!